# Visual Studio publish fails

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, iis-7, publish, xbap

I can rebuild and build my application without any errors, but I cannot publish it to my local IIS 7 web site.

I most certainly am missing a step...

It is an XBAP application that i'm trying to publish to a web site.

I created the web site by manually adding web site in IIS7 with default settings. I noticed that there are no sub folders in the web site (missing Application files and app data?)

When I try to publish I get the following error message:

```
Error: Failed to copy file 
Unable to add 'Application Files/...' to the Web site.  
Unable to add file 'Application Files\...'.  

Couldn't find the path
```

It fails on the copy from my app.publish\application files\\ to my publish folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added Everyone to my c:\inetpub\ with CRUD set. Rights issue. It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, when I move to vs2010 frm vs2008, y noted that I cannot publish anymore. It must be some kind of bug. Later I found that I can publish right-clicking in my main project in solution explorer and clicking in "publish" instead of doing it in the property window of the project.

Try it, maybe it will solve your problem too.

If It doesn't work you can also try this:

1. Go to the Publish directory
2. Highlight all files and folders
3. Right click and select Properties
4. Make sure the Read-only attribute checkbox is unchecked

Comment: No this didn't work. They are all writable in the publish folder. It is when copying them from publish folder to my destination folder in iis it fails.